# How to run pytest from console menu?

Tags: python, pytest, exec

I have console-menu, like:

```
if n == 1:
    exec('pytest test_1.py' ) # example, it doesn't work
elif n == 2:
    exec('pytest test_2.py' ) # example, it doesn't work
```

and login.py:

```
from functools import partial
import pytest_bdd

scenario = partial(pytest_bdd.scenario, '..\\login.feature')

@Scenario('login 2')
def test_2():
    pass()
```

and I want to start pytest for special methods (test_2), when I use this menu.
Now I runnig my pytest from PyCharm terminal or "run""debug".

How can I use exec() from python for call pytest?
Like:

```
exec('pytest -s login.test_2')
```

Is it possible? Or maybe it has another way?

Comment: See [Calling pytest from Python code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code)

Comment: @hoefling TY too, I will search and read information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can call pytest using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["pytest", "-s", "login.test_2"])
```

Comment: TY! It's work. Just one moment: need use normal path for py.test in venv and path for python files for testing.